# getline(cin, variable) not wanting to work properly in c++?

Tags: c++, getline

Here's my program so far:

```
int main()
{
    char choice = 'D';
    string inputString;

    cout << "Please input a string." << endl;

    getline(cin, inputString);

    LetterCount letterCount(inputString);

    while(choice != 'E')
    {
        cout << "Please choose from the following: " << endl
            << "A) Count the number of vowels in the string." << endl
            << "B) Count the number of consonants in the string." << endl
            << "C) Count both the vowels and consonants in the string." << endl
            << "D) Enter another string." << endl << "E) Exit the program." << endl;

        cin >> choice;

        if(choice == 'A' || choice == 'a')
        {
            cout << "There are " << letterCount.vowelCount() << " vowels in this string." << endl;
        }
        else if(choice == 'B' || choice == 'b')
        {
            cout << "There are " << letterCount.consonantCount() << " consonants in this string." << endl;
        }
        else if(choice == 'C' || choice == 'c')
        {
            cout << "There are " << letterCount.vowelCount() << " vowels and " << letterCount.consonantCount()
                << " consonants in this string, for a total of " << (letterCount.vowelCount() + letterCount.consonantCount())
                << " letters." << endl;
        }
        else if(choice == 'D' || choice == 'd')
        {
            cout << "Please type in another string." << endl;

            getline(cin, inputString);

            letterCount.setInputString(inputString);
        }
        else
        {
            choice = 'E';
        }
    }
}
```

I'm only including the main as it's the issue giver here, everything else functions properly.

The problem comes up when I use choice 'D' (input a new string.) as soon as enter is hit, the program returns right to the choice prompt and sets the inputString variable to blank (not the word blank, but nothing in it)

the first getline(cin, inputString) works perfectly fine, the second one is the issue giver...any suggestions?

Comment: check out the link ive added to my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think you have to add something like this:
`std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(),'\n');`
after your `cin >> choice`

The reason for this is, that the user actually entered 'D\n' but only 'D' fits into the choice variable, so the '\n' goes into the buffer of cin.
when you call getline, getline sees that '\n' in the buffer and returns with nothing in it...

that call above will remove all '\n' which are in the cin buffer.

Its explained quite well [here](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/showpost.php?p=1533281&postcount=4)

another solution would be something like:

```
char newline;
cin >> choice;
cin.get(newline);
```

This will only remove a single '\n' from the buffer.. (since `cin >> choice` added one `\n`)

Comment: ...that line of code makes little to no sense...what's it do? As I said, the first getline works fine, the second one (down at if loop for choice D) is the one giving issues.

Comment: Ahhh, awesome, makes good sense, I shall give it a go!

Do I need any special #include with it? Just throwing it in shoots back 5 errors

Comment: you will have to `#include <limits>` for `numeric_limits`

Answer (score 2):

Wouldnt it be better for you to use a switch case, such as this one?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
//Initialize
void newString();
void menu();
void switchCases(choice);

//Variables
string inputString;
char choice;
LetterCount letterCount(inputString);


int main(){
    menu();
}

void newString(){
    cout << "Please type in another string." << endl;
    getline(cin, inputString);
    letterCount.setInputString(inputString);
}

void menu(){
    cout << "Please choose from the following: " << endl
    << "A) Count the number of vowels in the string." << endl
    << "B) Count the number of consonants in the string." << endl
    << "C) Count both the vowels and consonants in the string." << endl
    << "D) Enter another string." << endl << "E) Exit the program." << endl;
    cin >> choice;
        newString();
}



void switchCases(char choice){
    switch (choice){
        case 'A':
        case 'a':{
            cout << "There are " << letterCount.vowelCount() << " vowels in this string." << endl;
            break;}
        case 'B':
        case 'b':{
            cout << "There are " << letterCount.consonantCount() << " consonants in this string." << endl;
            break;}
        case 'C':
        case 'c':{
            cout << "There are " << letterCount.vowelCount() << " vowels and " << letterCount.consonantCount()
            << " consonants in this string, for a total of " << (letterCount.vowelCount() + letterCount.consonantCount())
            << " letters." << endl;
            break;}
        case 'Q':
        case 'q':{
            break;}
        default:
        case 'D':
        case 'd':{
            main();}
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens if the person chooses f, or p, or a number for a choice? An if statement does what I needed it to do, so it remained my choice.  Not arguing the benefits of a switch, I love them, but an if worked out better in my case.

Comment: you can just add a `default:` statement in the switch case, i putted it at th end so if they entered something wrong it will display the menu again, you can just add a comment saying that option does not exist. Look at the example given by Travis, is exactly the same he just added the console message.

Answer (score 0):

You're not quite using getline correctly. Try using a skeleton like this...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>

using std::getline;
using std::string;
using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;


const string instructions = "Please choose from the following:\nA) Count the number of vowels in the string.\nB) Count the number of consonants in the string.\nC) Count both the vowels and consonants in the string.\nD) Enter another string.\nE) Exit the program.\n";

int main()
{
    // print instructions
    cout << instructions;

    // input text
    string text;

    bool processing = true;

    // start loop
    while (processing && getline(cin, text) && !text.empty())
    {
        // switch on input character
        switch (text[0])
        {
            case 'A':
            case 'a':
            {
                cout << "Doin A stuff" << endl;;
                break;
            }
            case 'B': 
            case 'b':
            {
                cout << "Doin B stuff" << endl;;
                break;
            }
            case 'C': 
            case 'c':
            {
                cout << "Doin C stuff" << endl;;
                break;
            }   
            case 'D': 
            case 'd':
            {
                cout << "Doin D stuff" << endl;;
                break;
            }
            case 'E':
            case 'e':
            {
                cout << "Exiting..." << endl;;
                processing = false;
                continue;
                break;
            }
            default:
            {
                cout << "I have no idea what you entered" << endl;
                processing = false;
                continue;
                break;
            }
        }   


        // print instructions for next loop
        cout << endl << instructions;
    }

    return 0;
}
```